# How do I capture the user input via a number button they press?

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

I'm building a calculator app and like the title states, I want to find a way where I can store my 'display value' in a variable to be used in math functions (+ - * /). The buttons do display as expected but the next use case would be to capture that value and place it in a variable.

```js
let numKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.num');
let onScreen = document.getElementById('display-screen');
let addNum = document.getElementById('add');
let subtractNum = document.getElementById('subtract');
let multiplyNum = document.getElementById('multiply');
let divideNum = document.getElementById('divide');
let decimal = document.getElementById('.');
let clearScreen = document.getElementById('clear');
let backSpace = document.getElementById('back-space');
let oneNum = document.getElementById('1');
let twoNum = document.getElementById('2');
let threeNum = document.getElementById('3');
let fourNum = document.getElementById('4');
let fiveNum = document.getElementById('5');
let sixNum = document.getElementById('6');
let sevenNum = document.getElementById('7');
let eightNum = document.getElementById('8');
let nineNum = document.getElementById('9');

oneNum.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('display-screen').textContent += '1';
});
twoNum.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //document.getElementById('display-screen').id;
  console.log(twoNum.value);
});
threeNum.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('display-screen').innerHTML += '3';
});
fourNum.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('display-screen').innerHTML += '4';
});
fiveNum.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('display-screen').innerHTML += '5';
});
sixNum.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('display-screen').innerHTML += '6';
});
sevenNum.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('display-screen').innerHTML += '7';
});
eightNum.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('display-screen').innerHTML += '8';
});
nineNum.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('display-screen').innerHTML += '9';
});
decimal.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('display-screen').innerHTML += '.';
});
clearScreen.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('display-screen').textContent = '';
})
```

```html
<div class="calc-keys">
  <div id="row-one">
    <button type="button" class="num" id="7">7</button>
    <button type="button" class="num" id="8">8</button>
    <button type="button" class="num" id="9">9</button>
    <button type="button" id="add">+</button>
  </div>

  <div id="row-two">
    <button type="button" class="num" id="4">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="num" id="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="num" id="6">6</button>
    <button type="button" id="subtract">-</button>
  </div>

  <div id="row-three">
    <button type="button" class="num" id="1" value="1">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="num" id="2" value="2">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="num" id="3">3</button>
    <button type="button" id="multply">x</button>
  </div>

  <div id="row-four">
    <button type="button" id=".">.</button>
    <button type="button" class="num" id="0">0</button>
    <button type="button" id="equals">=</button>
    <button type="button" id="division">/</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need additional details from me, any tips you can provide, and where exactly to look for the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already done the work needed to capture key presses. You can just make a global variable and update that variable in each `click` listener.

```
let value = 0;
twoNum.addEventListener('click', () => {
    value = (value * 10) + 2
    document.getElementById('display-screen').textContent = value; // The number will automatically be converted to a string here
});
```

or, if you want to store your number as a string:

```
let value = "";
twoNum.addEventListener('click', () => {
    value += "2";
    console.log("value as a number is:", parseInt(value);
    document.getElementById('display-screen').textContent = value;
});
```

---

Extra tip: You can save a lot of repetition here by using a `for` loop:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let button = document.getElementById(i);
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log("Button pressed:", i);
    });
}
```

Comment: QuinnFreedman - thank you, I think this solves it. I keep forgetting about for loops. That was my initial thought but wasn't confident enough that it would work. I just tried it out, and it seems that it does. It for sure beats repeating all of the event listeners. Much appreciated.

Comment: Actually - in the for loop - how would that capture the user input though if the value is not being used?